# Keras Model Predict Result is Invalid - AssertionError

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The goal of the model is to predict a random number using reinforcement learning. The issue seems to be at the act function the error I get is AssertionError on assert self.action_space.contains(action) which occurs once act returns Q. I'm lost when it comes to why its outputting -0.32666808 instead of a valid result like 108.2323 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
Just to be clear I am attempting to port code originally from [here](https://gist.github.com/kkweon/5605f1dfd27eb9c0353de162247a7456) which was originally made to solve the CartPole-v0 gym environment. I am trying to modify this code to solve the [HotterColder](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/hotter_colder.py) gym environment.

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import random
from gym import spaces
from gym.utils import seeding
from collections import deque
from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Dense, Flatten, RepeatVector, Reshape
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.models import Model,Sequential
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
class HotterColder(gym.Env):
    """Hotter Colder
    The goal of hotter colder is to guess closer to a randomly selected number
    After each step the agent receives an observation of:
    0 - No guess yet submitted (only after reset)
    1 - Guess is lower than the target
    2 - Guess is equal to the target
    3 - Guess is higher than the target
    The rewards is calculated as:
    (min(action, self.number) + self.range) / (max(action, self.number) + self.range)
    Ideally an agent will be able to recognise the 'scent' of a higher reward and
    increase the rate in which is guesses in that direction until the reward reaches
    its maximum
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.range = 100 # +/- value the randomly select number can be between
        self.bounds = 200  # Action space bounds

        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([-self.bounds]), high=np.array([self.bounds]))
        #self.action_space =  spaces.Discrete(self.bounds)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
        #self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([-self.bounds]), high=np.array([self.bounds]))
        #self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([-self.bounds]), high=np.array([self.bounds]))
        #self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4)#spaces.Box(low=np.array([-self.bounds]), high=np.array([self.bounds]))
        self.number = 0
        self.guess_count = 0
        self.guess_max = 2000
        self.observation = 0

        self.seed()
        self.reset()

    def seed(self, seed=None):
        self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
        return [seed]

    def step(self, action):
        assert self.action_space.contains(action)
        if action < self.number:
            self.observation = 1
            #print("num too low")

        elif action == self.number:
            self.observation = 2
            print("Action=" + str(action) + " Number Goal=" + str(self.number))
            print("Mission complete " + str(self.guess_count))
            self.done = True
            self.reset()
            #self.guess_count = 0
            #time.sleep(2)

        elif action > self.number:
            self.observation = 3
            #print('num too high')
        print("Action=" + str(action) + " Number Goal=" + str(self.number) + " Observation=" + str(self.observation))
        reward = ((min(action, self.number) + self.bounds) / (max(action, self.number) + self.bounds)) ** 2

        self.guess_count += 1
        done = self.guess_count >= self.guess_max
        #print(reward)
        return self.observation, reward, done, {"number": self.number, "guesses": self.guess_count}

    def reset(self):
        #self.number = self.np_random.uniform(-self.range,self.range)
        self.number = self.np_random.uniform(-self.range,self.range, size=(1,))
        self.guess_count = 0
        self.observation = 0
        return self.observation
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.input_dim = 1
        self.output_dim = env.action_space.shape[0]
        print(self.output_dim)
        self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Dense(3,input_shape=(1,)))
        self.model.add(Dense(8))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(32))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(16))
        self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(self.output_dim))
        #model.add(Activation('softmax'))
        #sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
        #self.model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=net)
        self.model.compile( loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
        #print(self.model.summary())
        #self.model = model
        #return model

    def act(self, X, eps=1.0):
        if np.random.rand() < eps:
            return self.env.action_space.sample()
        print(self.env.action_space.sample())
        #X = float(X)
        print(X)
        X = np.asarray(X,)
        #print(X)
        X = X.reshape(-1, )
        print(X)
        #print(X.shape)
        #print(self.env.action_space.sample())
        #print(X)
        #X = np.array(X)
        Q = self.model.predict(X)
        print(Q)
        print(np.argmax(Q, 1)[0])
        #return np.argmax(Q, 1)[0]
        return(Q)

    def train(self, X_batch, y_batch):
        return self.model.train_on_batch(X_batch, y_batch)

    def predict(self, X_batch):
        #print(self.model.summary())
        #print(X_batch)
        #time()
        return self.model.predict_on_batch(X_batch)


def create_batch(agent, memory, batch_size, discount_rate):
    sample = random.sample(memory, batch_size)
    sample = np.asarray(sample)

    s = sample[:, 0]
    a = sample[:, 1].astype(np.int8)
    r = sample[:, 2]
    s2 = sample[:, 3]
    d = sample[:, 4] * 1.
    #print(a)
    #time.sleep()
    #print(s)
    X_batch = np.vstack(s)
    #print(X_batch)
    y_batch = agent.predict(X_batch)
    #print(np.max(agent.predict(np.vstack(s2))))
    #print(np.arange(batch_size))
    #time.sleep(5)
    #y_batch[np.arange(batch_size), a] = r + discount_rate * np.max(agent.predict(np.vstack(s2)), 1) * (1 - d)
    #print(y_batch)
    #print(r + discount_rate * np.max(agent.predict(np.vstack(s2)), 1) * (1 - d))
    #y_batch[np.arange(batch_size)] = r + discount_rate * np.max(agent.predict(np.vstack(s2)), 1) * (1 - d)

    return X_batch, y_batch


def print_info(episode, reward, eps):
    #print("[Episode {episode:>5}] Reward: {reward:>5} EPS: {eps:>3.2f}")
    print("Episode " + str(episode) + " Reward " + str(reward) + " EPS " + str(eps))


def main():
    n_episode = 1000
    discount_rate = 0.99
    n_memory = 5000
    batch_size = 32
    eps = 1.0
    min_eps = 0.1
    #env_name = 'CartPole-v0'
    #env = gym.make(env_name)
    env = HotterColder()
    agent = Agent(env)
    memory = deque()

    # CartPole-v0 Clear Condition
    # Average reward per episode > 195.0 over 100 episodes
    LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS = deque()

    for episode in range(n_episode):
        done = False
        s = env.reset()
        print("s: " + str(s))
        eps = max(min_eps, eps - 1/(n_episode/2))
        episode_reward = 0
        while not done:
            a = agent.act(s, eps)
            s2, r, done, info = env.step(a)
            episode_reward += r

            if done and episode_reward < 200:
                r = -100

            memory.append([s, a, r, s2, done])

            if len(memory) > n_memory:
                memory.popleft()

            if len(memory) > batch_size:
                X_batch, y_batch = create_batch(agent, memory, batch_size, discount_rate)
                agent.train(X_batch, y_batch)

            s = s2

        print_info(episode, episode_reward, eps)
        LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS.append(episode_reward)
        if len(LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS) > 100:
            LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS.popleft()

        if np.mean(LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS) >= 195.0:
            #print(f"Game solved in {episode + 1} with average reward {np.mean(LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS)}")
            print("Game solved in " + str(episode + 1) + " with average reward  " + str(np.mean(LAST_100_GAME_EPISODE_REWARDS)) )

    env.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So you're using Q value as your next action? Why would you do that?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of your error?

Comment: [-20.28334]
1
[1]
[[-0.01734143]]
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen4.py", line 222, in <module>
    main()
  File "gen4.py", line 192, in main
    s2, r, done, info = env.step(a)
  File "gen4.py", line 49, in step
    assert self.action_space.contains(action)
AssertionError